# Phonegap 2.1 cordova.exec update

Tags: cordova

I had this JS in one of the plugins. I am trying to port it to Phonegap 2.1. The problem is that the receiver code cannot resolve the caller function name, it says `<null>`.

```
    PhoneGap.exec("localizable.get", name,GetFunctionName(success));
```

I tried

```
    cordova.exec("localizable.get", name, GetFunctionName(success));
    cordova.exec("localizable.get", name, success);
    cordova.exec("localizable.get", name, success.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exec arguments should be:

```
cordova.exec(successfunction, errorfunction, "service", "action", [arguments]);
```